# React-Native - Create a grid

Tags: javascript, react-native

The following code generates a row of 10 squares with random numbers in them. I'm trying to somehow make it a grid of 10 rows by 10 columns but I'm stuck here. I'd like to limit the columns in a row to 10. So if the var limit is 40, it would create 4 rows by 10 columns. 60 would create 6 rows by 10 columns, etc.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Decrease, Increase, GetScore } from '../actions';
import { CardSection, Square } from './common';

class TableGenerator extends Component {
  clickable(sq) {
    this.props.Decrease(sq);
    console.log(this.props.score);
  }

  generateRandom() {
    // Random number generator
    function* rand() {
      while (true) {
        yield Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      }
    }
    const it = rand();
    const nums = [];
    const limit = 10;
    for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
      nums.push(it.next().value);
    }
    return nums.map((sq, i) =>
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={i}
        onPress={() => this.clickable(sq)}
      >
        <Square style={{ height: 30, width: 30 }}>
          {nums[i]}
        </Square>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <CardSection style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          {this.generateRandom()}
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection>
          <Text>Current Score: </Text>
          <Text>{this.props.score}</Text>
        </CardSection>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    score: state.scoreReducer
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { Decrease, Increase, GetScore })(TableGenerator);
```

Comment: I would simply use an outer container to limit the width, and force the extra squares to the next row.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Did it and specified flexWrap.

Comment: posted an answer. I didn't use flexWrap. but it's not a big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting a quick answer for other people who stumble upon this thread.

You can simply use an outer container to limit the width, so that the children `square`s will be forced into the next row once they fill the entire row.

**In outer container render function**

```
<Container style={width: '300px'}>
  // iterate the and render the children squares
</Container>
```

**In `square` component render function**

```
<Square style={width: '30px', height: '30px', float: 'left', display: 'inline-block'}>
  // content
</Square>
```

I happened to have something similar in my pet project, you can see it in action [here](https://github.com/EdmundLeex/tic_tac_toe_on_chrome_extension/tree/master/app/popup/src/scripts/components).